# hash must be unicode or bytes, not sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy

Tags: python, flask

Estoy desarrollando una web con python Flask y en el inicio de sesión he usado este código.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
if request.method == "POST":
    email_login = request.form.get("email-login")
    password_login = request.form.get("password-login")

    email_login_data = db.execute("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=:email", 
    {"email":email_login}).fetchall()
    password_login_data = db.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=:email", {"email":email_login}).fetchall()


    if email_login_data is None:
        flash("No username", "danger")
        return render_template('login.html')

    else:
        for password_data in password_login_data:
            if sha256_crypt.verify(password_login, password_data):
                flash("You are now login","success")
                return redirect(url_for('likes'))
            else:
                flash('Incorrect password','danger')
                return render_template('login.html')
```

Primero tengo un registro donde encripto las contraseñas con passlib.hash, pero al verificar
si están bien, me sale este error:

```
TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy
```

Estoy usando sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
```

No se muy bien que hacer, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que como el error especifica le estás pasando a `passlib.sha256_crypt.verify` un objeto `sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy` que es un objeto proxy que usa sqlalchemy para cada fila de la consulta y que actúa como intermediario de acceso con el objeto. Puedes acceder a los valores de las columnas (AKA atributos del objeto) mediante la sintaxis normal de Python para referenciar un atributo, la notación `.nombre_atributo`:

```
password_data.password
```

por lo tanto deberías hacer:

```
sha256_crypt.verify(password_login, password_data.password)
```

Dejo un ejemplo completo reproducible, sin usar flask y con sqlite3 para simplificar:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


class Usuario(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session()

usuario1 = Usuario("fulanito@foomail.com", sha256_crypt.hash("123456"))
session.add(usuario1)

session.commit()


def login(email_login, password_login):
    password_data = session.execute(
        "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=:email",
        {"email": email_login}
        ).fetchone()

    if password_data is None:
        print(f"No user - {email_login}")
    elif sha256_crypt.verify(password_login, password_data.password):
        print(f"You are now login - {email_login}")
    else:
        print(f'Incorrect password - {email_login}')


login("menganito@foomail.com", "123456")
login("fulanito@foomail.com", "789789")
login("fulanito@foomail.com", "123456")

session.close()
```